# Why I cannot submit this form with one click if the input is active?

Tags: reactjs

The problem seems to be that I'm mutating the component state so it won't trigger the submit action until I wait (?) for the state mutation to be completed. It doesn't make much sense to me and I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now.

Just to be clear, I'd like to:

1. click on the input field
2. show the hidden 'hello' div
3. click submit, then it will hide the 'hello' div and send the form

What's happening:

1. click on the input field
2. show the hidden 'hello' div
3. click submit
4. the 'hello' div is hidden
5. I have to submit the form again

**[Here is a live demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYaZyr?editors=1011)**

And the code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._submit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text" onFocus={this._focus} onBlur={this._blur} />
        </label>

        {this.state.show ? <div>hello</div> : null}

        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }

  _focus = () => {
    console.log('########## focus')

    this.setState({ show: true })
  }
  _blur = () => {
    console.log('########## blur')

    this.setState({ show: false })
  }

  _submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log('########## submit')
  }

  state = { show: false }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the state in the wrong place...

Here you go:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { show: false };

  _focus = () => {
    console.log("########## focus");
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };
  _blur = () => {
    console.log("########## blur");
  };

  _submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ show: false });
    console.log("########## submit");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._submit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text" onFocus={this._focus} onBlur={this._blur} />
        </label>
        {this.state.show ? <div>hello</div> : null}
        <div>
          <button type="sumit">submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/69nzv4k6k)

Comment: Hey, thanks! I thought about this implementation too, the problem is that if the form has more than one text input, the 'hello' div would only be hidden on submit and would be displayed even if other input is active: https://codesandbox.io/s/p7p7vnrlzq

Comment: Thank you, imagine that each hidden div is a tip for the input field, so if you're on a given input, you don't want to see the tip for the other input, right? I'm sorry, I'm terrible at explaining things. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If it's just a 'tip' then why not simply add a placeholder? What you are doing is usually reserved for validation... like if a field is required...

Comment: Because I'm not the one to decide it. Also if it were reserved for validation, the same principles would apply. As a user I don't want to see if the field is required if I already filled it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182768/discussion-between-sakobu-and-marvelouswololo).